# Invalid path in TortoiseSVN error message

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, working-copy

When updating my subversion repository using TortoiseSVN I get the following error message:

Path 'C:\OTMS Rhapsody Model\trunk\OTMS_rpy\C:' is not in the working copy

Clearly the path is invalid as it contains a colon within the folder structure, but why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution was not found by me, but apparently there was a folder or file named "C:\" in the repository. No one knows how it got there (especially in a folder structure on a Windows machine!) but, once the offending article was deleted, all was right with the world.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to checkout on Windows. We found that our designer was able to create a file in our SVN with a name like "scss/../css/style.css", but we also don't know how. He was using a Mac when he did this.

We were not able to directly delete the file from SVN on Windows, it was also showing an error. So we had to backup the entire folder content where this file was located and delete the upper folder.

Comment: This is a good answer. But next time, consider mentioning your answer first and make that clear, then you can provide your own way of recreating the problem.